# Google Chrome makes bird chirping noises

Tags: google-chrome, audio

I've been hearing the same bird chirping noises for quite a while. At first, I wasn't sure where it was coming from. However, I am having the same sounds come from my Imac and my work laptop. The only common link is that the sound happens when both are running google chrome.

It's really annoying and I don't know why it happens or how to shut it off. Anyone have thoughts on how to pinpoint what is causing the sound and how to shut it off?

EDIT:

1. I'm not running any twitter extensions.
2. I should be running the most up to date version of Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.48 m)
3. I do sometimes have gmail open, but I thought it makes a chime sound instead of chirping
4. It appears to do it even when there is no "new tab" open

Comment: Does it matter which site/page the browser is on?  How often is this happening? Which version of Chrome?  Have you got any add-ons/plug-ins installed in Chrome?

Comment: Do you have any twitter clients/addons installed?

Comment: Do you have Gmail page open? If people send you messages directly (not email, but Google Hangout messages) those are usually the chirping sound.

Comment: Does it do it with only the new tab page open?